# CKEditor buttons not showing

Tags: wysiwyg

I'm using Drupal CKEditor module 7.x-1.13 and CKEditor 4.3.2.
Everything is installed and appears to work fine... except that there are some buttons that don't appear despite being configured to do so, notably "Select All" and the justify left/right/centre/justified buttons.
Here are the buttons as configured:

[image: Here is a picture of the buttons configuration screen]

And here are the buttons as they appear:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to get and install the Full Package here: http://ckeditor.com/download

Then the missing buttons will show up.

Comment: This worked, thank you. Although it seemed necessary also to delete the browser cache for the new setting to take effect.

Comment: Right - I forgot about that. CKEditor settings can be very "sticky". Glad it worked for you.

Comment: @DaveBruns I am still having problem. All buttons show up even the plugin buttons. I have a full version, but custom buttons do not show up. I am trying to use ckeditor insert module to insert file fields.